# What does this strange C++ syntax do?

Tags: c++, pytorch, cc

From what I understand, 3 arguments are being passed to m.def(). I don't understand the syntax of the second argument passed, i.e. [] (Observable...){} What does this mean?

```
m.def(
  "DumpHistogramFile",
  [](Observable<NetBase>::Observer* ob) {
    HistogramNetObserver* hist_ob =
        dynamic_cast_if_rtti<HistogramNetObserver*>(ob);
    hist_ob->DumpHistogramFile();
  },
  pybind11::arg("ob"));
```

I found this syntax in the [pytorch source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/caffe2/quantization/server/pybind.cc)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is a function that takes a pointer to an `Observer` and doesn't return anything. When executed, it calls `DumpHistogramFile`. This is called a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).